# I cant create correct omron hmi crc code with arduino

Tags: algorithm, arduino, crc, human-interface

Hello I am trying to communicate omron hmi with arduino via modbus rtu. I'm actually just listening the data with arduino so i can analize the data transmition. But when I tried to create its crc I was not able get corrrect crc data. Below there is algorithm and the code I wrote. If anyone know the problem please help me.

> Blockquote
> Example of CRC-16 Calculation
> A message is processed 1 byte at a time in a 16-bit processing register called the CRC register.

> 1 A default value of FFFF hex is set in the CRC register.

> 2 An XOR is taken of the contents of the CRC register and the first byte of the message, and the
> result is returned to the CRC register.

> 3 The contents of the CRC register is shifted 1 bit to the right, and 0 is placed in the MSB.

> 4 If the bit shifted from the LSB is 0, step 3 is repeated (i.e., the contents of the register is shifted
> 1 more bit).
> If the bit shifted from the LSB is 1, an XOR is taken of the contents of the CRC register and
> A001 hex, and the result is returned to the CRC register.

> 5 Steps 3 and 4 are repeated until the contents of the register have been shifted 8 bits to the right.

> 6 If the end of the message has not been reached, an XOR is taken of the next byte of the
> message and the CRC register, the result is returned to the CRC register, and the procedure is
> repeated from step 3.

> 7 The result (the value in the CRC register) is placed in the lower byte of the message.
> Example of Appending the Result
> If the calculated CRC value is 1234 hex, this is appended as follows to the command frame.

```
 crc=0xFFFF;  //A default value of FFFF hex is set in the CRC register.
 LSB=0; 
 cnt=0;
 
  
 Serial.print("CRC-");
 Serial.println(crc,BIN);
 for(i=0;i<13;i++)
 {
                      //An XOR is taken of the contents of the CRC register and the first byte of the message, and the
                      //result is returned to the CRC register.
                      //If the end of the message has not been reached, an XOR is taken of the next byte of the
                      //message and the CRC register, the result is returned to the CRC register, and the procedure is
                      //repeated from step 3.
  crc=crc^data[i]; 
  LSB=crc&1;
  cnt=0;

  while(cnt<8)       //Steps 3 and 4 are repeated until the contents of the register have been shifted 8 bits to the right.
  {

    crc=crc>>1;             //The contents of the CRC register is shifted 1 bit to the right, and 0 is placed in the MSB.
    crc=crc&0x7fff;
    cnt++;
  
    //LSBe=LSB;
    LSB=crc&1;
    if(cnt==8)break;
    Serial.print("LSB-");
 Serial.println(LSB,HEX);
 
// If the bit shifted from the LSB is 0, step 3 is repeated (i.e., the contents of the register is shifted 1 more bit).
//If the bit shifted from the LSB is 1, an XOR is taken of the contents of the CRC register and
//A001 hex, and the result is returned to the CRC register.

    if(LSB==0)
    {
      crc=crc>>1;
      crc=crc&0x7fff;
      cnt++;
       Serial.print("CRC2-");
 Serial.println(crc,BIN);
    }
    else if(LSB==1)
    {
       crc=crc^operation;
     Serial.print("CRC3-");
 Serial.println(crc,BIN);
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For each byte of data:

```
crc ^= data[i];
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001;
```

That is all.